# How i can measure time of thread pool in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, time

**I have used two different approach to measure time of threads but result are not matching**

```
    **Public void Main()** 
{
        Timer timer = new Timer();
                    int timetotal;


                    timer.start();
            int numberOfThreads=5;
            ExecutorService pool= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
            List<Future<Boolean>> futureList = new ArrayList<Future<Boolean>>();
            Set<ReadProcess_MongoDB> callList = new HashSet<ReadProcess_MongoDB>();
            CompletionService<ReadProcess_MongoDB> taskCompletionService;
            taskCompletionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<ReadProcess_MongoDB>(pool);

            Collection<Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>> list;
            list = new LinkedList<Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>>();

            for(int i=0;i<numberOfThreads;i++)
               list.add((Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>) new ReadProcess_MongoDB(i));

                try {

                    for (Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB> callable : list) {
                        taskCompletionService.submit(callable);
                  }
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    Future<ReadProcess_MongoDB> result = taskCompletionService.take(); 

                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // no real error handling. Don't do this in production!
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // no real error handling. Don't do this in production!
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    pool.shutdown();
                     System.out.println("Done :)");
                     timer.stop();
                     System.out.println("Total consumed Time"+ timer.elapsed());
                 }
```

**Other time I put in Call method()**

```
 **public String call()**
     {

          Timer timer = new Timer();
            int timetotal;


            timer.start();
                DBCursor cursor = coll.find(whereQuery);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ReadProcess_MongoDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            timer.stop();
            usedTimeForQueryProcess = timer.elapsed();
            System.out.println("Thread Number="+this.threadNumber+  "   MongoDB_readQuery used time "+usedTimeForQueryProcess);
            System.out.println("runing.....");
      return Objects.toString(usedTimeForQueryProcess);
     }
```

In call Function, system print time of every thread and in Main function only display totaltime.Here I try check manually ,but both time are not matching .But bigger problem is Main function show less time than total time  of all threads(Call function).
 I have also tried to return used time from Call function But it is also create problem convert to long (especially runtime problem ).
Time of Both function
Main function time =289
Call function time=510(5 thread).
Would please somebody expain why this happening and how i can make right measurement ?

Comment: Hmm, what do you want to achieve by measuring this? Do you have a particular problem to solve or is this just intellectual curiosity?

Comment: @fge I am developing application to test work load performance(read/write) of diffrent type of database(sql and noSql) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Main time is lower than the **total** of each of your jobs because they are running in parallel.  If you reduce your thread pool size down to 1 then you will the numbers be more like what you expect.

This is one of the benefits of doing multithreaded programming, getting more work done in less time than if it were done sequentially.

Comment: There is no difference even  afrer numberOfThred=1 .It is   almost same time as i mention in question(Main function time 278 ) and one thead time 102 (Call Funtion)

Comment: I'm confused, with one thread it's only 102 for the thread and 278 overall.  That seems perfectly logical to me

Comment: How it is logical ? would you please explain?

Comment: You have a unit of work to do that takes about 100 milliseconds to complete, and you do 5 of them in parallel.  This takes a little over 100 milliseconds as they all work at the same time, but the cumulative time of them is over 500 (5 * 100).  The elapsed time is still only a little over 100 though.  Your main method is adding a little overhead itself putting the total up to 278.  Does that make more sense?